# Returning value from Coldfusion CFC called with JQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I'm trying to call an CFC component with Ajax. But I need to pass the value returned by the CFC to my javascript routine. The `done` function creates the correct message when I display `msg` in an alert. But the `ret` variable is never populated with that value. I need the value returned to alter the javascript data flow.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var ret = $.ajax({
              type: "post",
              url: "cfc/CFCSemae.cfc",
              data: {
                  method: "verificaCadastro",
                  returnformat: "plain",
                  queryformat: "column",
                  nro_cadastro: num_cad
      },
      dataType: "html",
      }).done(function(msg){ return msg; });

alert(ret);
```

Comment: That's not how callback functions work. Instead of `return msg;` do this inside your `.done` function: `ret = msg;`

Comment: I'd also use `success` and `error` callbacks instead of `done` or `complete`

Comment: i've tried this but now i only get ret = undefined... if i alert(msg) inside done function, i get the value... if i do ret = msg inside ajax call and do alert(ret) outside, i get undefined X_x

Comment: I don't think you understand async programming yet

Comment: Have you tried something like Firebug to watch the request / response?

Answer (score 2):

The following code should do it for you, however **understand** that when you are doing async requests, you'll only get the result when the callback is executed. Your code will simply call you `$.ajax` function, but it will not wait for a response (as it if it's in a different thread). When the response is ready, the callback `complete` is executed. If the response return a success message (HTTP Status 200), the `success` callback is called, `error` is called otherwise.

```
//somewhere in your script
var ret = '';

// then at the ajax request
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "cfc/CFCSemae.cfc",
    data: { method: "verificaCadastro", returnformat: "plain",
            queryformat: "column", nro_cadastro: num_cad },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // make sure your serverside function can return json
    success: function(data) {
        //your own validation to check whether 'data' is a valid response 
        ret = data;
    },
    error: function(xhr, msg) {
        // handle error
    }
});
```

Please read the following article about ajax programming. This will give you a better understanding of what asynchronous programming is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

*Edit*: corrected misspelling

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is asynchronous, you cannot return a value from the callback with out making a synchronous call. You really don't want to do that.

Provide a callback function for the success: handler. You can add your logic there for placing the returned data into your JavaScript flow.