# cfajaxproxy and Ajax to work with verifyclient function

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion, cfc, cfajaxproxy

I want to implement verifyclient in some functions in a cfc. I am aware that the follow syntax will works, but I don't know how to implement it within a ajax call. Example:

```
<cfajaxproxy cfc="cfc.cls_queries" jsclassname="cls_queries">

<script type="text/javascript">
  var cfcQuery = new cls_queries(); // reference the cfc object

  ..some functions....()

</script>
```

And I have another piece of code where I'm using plain Ajax as follow:

```
$.ajax({
   async:    false,
   type:     "POST",
   url:      "resources/cfc/cls_queries.cfc",
   dataType: "json",
   data: {
      method: "get_someInformation",
      cidm: lv_userID
   },
   success: function(data){}
});
```

How can I replace the url, data{method, and parameters} with the object (**cfcQuery**)  that reference the cfc?

Comment: Implementation of the verifyclient function is not documented so you may try reverse engineering it if you have strong reasons to do so, but I would rather not.

Comment: My problem is not with the verifyclient function, it is about replacing the url, and data {method, @params} with the object that reference the ColdFusion component.
I am thinking something like 
$.ajax({
  async: false,
  type: "POST",
  dataType:  "json", 
  cfcQuery.get_someInformation(lv_userID),
  success: function(data){
  }
});

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180544/returning-value-from-coldfusion-cfc-called-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: No really, however I figure out the problem: mixing unnecessarily Ajax with cfcQuery variable. Steps:
1-Before the loading the javascript on the cfm, declare the cfajaxproxy, and reference the function within the javascript.
2-At the top of the js, declare the new object that is going to reference the cfc
Call the function in the cfc. Example: 
var data = cfcQuery.get_student(
        null,
        id,
        fname,
        lname,
 null,
        null,
        null,
        null
      );
And after that parse the success result (data) to manipulate the content

Answer (score 1):

As David mentioned. You may use the following code to make the ajax call:

```
<cfajaxproxy cfc="cfc.cls_queries" jsclassname="cls_queries">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cfcQuery = new cls_queries();
    var result = cfcQuery.get_someInformation(cidm = lv_userID);
</script>
```